# TransitionTo triggers two routes

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I have two routes for my places resource: One overview '/places', and one detail view '/places/:id.

```
this.resource('places', function () {
    this.resource('place', { path: '/:place_id' }, function () {
    });
});
```

In my application controller, i.e. at the start of the app, I want to perform a redirect if some conditions are met. I do the transition via

```
if (condition) {
    this.store.find('place', 0).then(
        function (place) {
            self.transitionTo('place.index', place);
        }
    );
}
```

When I log the transitions via `LOG_TRANSITIONS: true`, it outputs `Transitioned into 'places.place.index'` - which looks good.

However, it triggers two routes to render a template: The PlacesRoute and the PlaceRoute. And since both use a different outlet to render their templates, I see the content from both.

How can I prevent this behavior? When I later perform a transition to another place, everything works as I expect it to be, i.e. it only triggers the PlacesRoute (and not the PlaceRoute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd suggest to rename 'place' resource to 'places.place' (`this.resource('places.place', ...)` or `this.route('place', ...)` for latest versions of Ember).

Secondary, what are you trying to do? When Ember handling transition to child route, it's should load and render routes up in the hierarchy (application route->places route->place route in case transition to `places.place` route). If route already presented (rendered), nothing happens (ex: transition from `places.place` with place id 1 to `places.place` with place id 2 will not trigger rerendering for application and places routes).

Think about child routes as progressive specification of displayed information: in `places` route user sees list of places and in `places.place` route he sees list of places and information about one particular place.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clearing some points. But the transition that works as expected is not from /places/1 to /places/2, it's from /somewhereElse to /places/1 that does not trigger the PlacesRoute (or at least, it does not render the template).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it might be because of wrong way of declaration for child resource. Debug to the rescue! :)

Comment: Ok, I think your last sentence is the answer for me - I will try something else :)